# Why does powershell run old versions of my file?

Tags: powershell

I tried to run my powershell script, got some errors and then fixed those errors. Then I try to run it again, but my old code is still running. I'm getting error messages on old import statements that are no longer there. I've tried restarting powershell multiple times but to no avail.

This is my error line

```
Add-Type -Path .\CSharp\KeyBoardHook.cs
```

But it no longer exists in my script. It looks like this now

```
Add-Type -Path "..\.\CSharp\KeyBoardHook.cs"
```

I have tried adding "Remove-Type" before the script - doesn't work. I have also tried adding "Remove-Variable *" and "Remove-Module *", but that didn't do anything either. I'm pretty new to powershell and I haven't stumbled upon a similar issue in any other language, that I can remember at least. Is there some wise powershell wizard out there willing to help me?

Comment: While  you can use `Import-Module -Force` to force reloading of a module in a given session, this only works for _PowerShell code_, any modified on-demand-compiled C# code cannot be reloaded - you'll need to start a new session. If the problem is that an old, duplicate version of your module exists _in the file-system_ and is accidentally [auto-loaded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules#module-auto-loading), use `Get-Module -ListAvailable <your-module-name>` to find all versions.

Comment: For debugging PowerShell code with custom C# types, I find it helpful to use VSCode with its PowerShell extension. With the extension option "Create Temporary Integrated Console" enabled, a new PowerShell session gets automatically created for each debug session, making sure you always run the _current_ version of the code.